# Get item from grouped dataTable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, group-by, dataset, datarow

I want to get `item[col]` from `dataRow` but item in `dt1.rows` return two element `item[0]` contains the unique ID and `item[1]` return all attributes i want to add to the row

```
var dataSet = ToDataSet(rows.GroupBy(a => a["UniqueID"]).ToDictionary(gdc => 
gdc.FirstOrDefault()).ToList());

DataTable dt1 = dataSet.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow item in dt1.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, item[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);}`

    //item[col] return two element, the first element contains uniqueID and the second element contains all attributes              
}
```

How can i get the `item.ItemArray[0]`?

[image]

Comment: you always want 0th number item for all your columns or you want item per column?

Comment: string[] results = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(0)).ToArray();

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but that's doesn't work  , i want for item UniqueName to get  the columns which in item.itemArray[1] like picture

Comment: I want to get the Item.itemarray[0] [1] ? how to do that

Comment: did u want to retrieve `xxxxx` from `uniqueId`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row that contains UniqueID as key from your current `item` like,

```
var results = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(0)).ToList();
```

OR you can also use column name instead of index like,

```
var results = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("UniqueID")).ToList();
```